# Question about strcmp

Tags: c++

For example we have two strings:

```
string s = "cat";
string s1 = "dog";
```

Is it correct to write the following method?

```
int a = strcmp(s, s1);
```

Or what will be correct form?

Comment: `strcmp` is a C library function - if you're writing C++ code you would normally use methods from the `string` class.

Comment: I'd highly recommend using the c++ string class in c++ programs. Use #include <string> and std::string.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

C++'s `std::string` can be compared directly, so you could just write e.g.

```
if (s == s1)
  cout << "the strings are equal" << endl;
else if (s < s1)
  cout << "the first string is smaller" << endl;
else
  ...
```

But if you really need the integer value, you could use [the `.compare` method](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/).

```
int a = s.compare(s1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness, while you should use the built-in string functions when you can, there are common situations where you often need to compare a C-style null terminated string to a C++ string.  For instance you will constantly run into situations where a system call returns a pointer to a C-string.

You can choose to turn the C-string into a C++ string and compare them

```
string  s1 = "cat";
string  s2 = "dog";
const char *s3 = "lion";

if (s1 == string(s3))
    cout << "equal" << endl;
else
    cout << "not equal" << endl;
```

or compare the C++'s underlying C-string to the other C-string:

```
a = strcmp(s1.c_str(), s3);
```